# Certificates compartments (certmgr.msc)?

Tags: security, windows-7, certificate, certificate-authority

After reading a while , Im trying to understand what kind of certificates will be found at :

- Personal
- Other People
- Trusted Root Certicfiation Authorities

will *personal* will contains only private keys ? I'm a bit confused.

What about certificates which arent trusted and I manually trust them  , where will they be ?

Also , Why do I only have the `CurrentUser` Tab  in my computer ? where is the `local computer` tab ?

*here is a picture from the internet. I only have the "current user" Node....*

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest part to answer is why you only see 'CurrentUser'. That's all that certmgr.msc gives you. Looking at the screenshot, you see 'Console2' in the title, not 'certmgr'. It's a custom mmc:

Run mmc.exe, under 'File' select 'Add/Remove Snap-ins' and choose 'Certificates' on the left, you are now ask to choose which types of Certificates. Select 'My user account', then 'add' 'Certificates' again and this time select 'Computer account'. Now you have both currentUser and LocalMachine in your mmc, just like at the screen shot.

'Personal' has all your certificates. I think they all have the private keys, but not all of them are exportable.

'Other people' has the public parts of other user's certificates, that you may use to sign something.

Comment: See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757138%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for an explanation of which content belongs into which store.